# pushd popd global directory stack?

Tags: shell

I do not know if there is a valid way to do this. But, have always wanted to see if its possible.

I know that pushd, popd and dirs are useful for a number of things like copying between directories you have recently visited.

But, is there a way in which you can keep a global stack? So that if I push something (using pushd) in one terminal it gets reflected in another (maybe only the terminals in that login session).

Comment: Pushd and popd are builtin commands and the dir stack is maintained by each shell process. Yes, there is a way to have a global stack. Many ways in fact. Have you attempted anything yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a pair of shell functions and a temporary file.

Your temporary file would be named something like '`/home/me/.directory_stack`' and would simply contain a list of directories:

```
/home/me
/etc
/var/log
```

Your 'push_directory' function would simply add the current directory to the list.  The 'pop_directory' function would pull the most recent off of the list and switch to that directory.  Storing the stack in a file like this ensures that the information exists across all open terminals (and even across reboots).

Here are some example functions (warning: only lightly tested)

```
directory_stack=/home/me/.directory_stack
function push_dir() {
    echo $(pwd) >> $directory_stack
    cd $1
}
function pop_dir() {
    [ ! -s $directory_stack ] && return
    newdir=$(sed -n '$p' $directory_stack)
    sed -i -e '$d' $directory_stack
    cd $newdir
}
```

Add that to your `.bashrc` and they'll automatically be defined every time you log into the shell.

Comment: Bah, it looks like sarnold had the same idea that I did and beat me to the punch.  I'll leave my answer since it uses a different technique, but for the record he was first.

Comment: The `sed '$p'` and `sed '$d'` programs are _perfect_; much nicer than my horrible arithmetic. I figured the standard Unix tools should have an easier mechanism for removing and returning the last line of a file...

Comment: Thank you. I was missing this since 20+ years. Worked like a charm so far.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to write a few shell functions and use them in place of `pushd` and `popd`. Something like the following (untested) functions might do the job:

```
mypushd() { echo "$1" >> ~/.dir_stack ; cd "$1" }
mypopd() { dir=`tail -1 ~/.dir_stack` ; cd "$dir" ;
           foo=`wc -l ~/.dir_stack | egrep -o '[0-9]+'` ;
           ((foo=$foo-1)) ;
           mv ~/.dir_stack ~/.dir_stack_old ;
           head -n $foo ~/.dir_stack_old > ~/.dir_stack }
```

You could get rid of some of the uglier bits if you write a small program that returns and removes the last line of the file.

Comment: Thanks! This seems quick and simple. I'll try to duplicate this in python/perl if required. I was initially thinking if bash itself had some environment variable to do this. i guess thats not the case.

Comment: The trouble with trying to re-do this in Python or Perl is that the `chdir(2)` system call can only influence the current process. If you really want this in Python, you might also like to look at [IPython](http://ipython.org/) -- I understand it tries to be a shell replacement for interactive computing tasks. But if you want to keep using your shell, don't waste any time trying to reproduce these functions in any other language -- [bta's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9916812/377270) is probably the best you can do without a huge amount of work.